# Lagrange multipliers to find min/max with parabola

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Use Lagrange multipliers to find extreme values of $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ on part of parabola $y = x^2 - 1, -2 \le x \le 2$

I got the equations

> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 2x = \lambda(-2x)\\ 
> 2y = \lambda\\ 
> y  - x^2 = -1
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

Using the equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$

From this I see (system of equations):

> $y = \frac{\lambda}{2}$, $\{x = 0$, or,  $\lambda = 0\}$, and $x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2} + 1}$ (using last eq and solving for $x$)

Critical points of $f$ is $(0, 0)$

Using the lambda equations, we see possible points $(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)$

Using the edges of $g$, we get the points $(-2, 3), (2, 3)$

So the set finally is

$\{(0, 0), (-2, 3), (2, 3), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)\}$

I get max = $13$ [**correct**]

I get min = 0 [**wrong**]

The minimum is supposed to be 3/4.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Notice that the critical point of $f$ - that you mentioned - is not on the parabola. So, you shouldn't consider the point $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2x = \lambda (-2x)$$

$$2y=\lambda$$
$$y-x^2=-1$$

Case $1$: If $x=0$, $y=-1$.

Case $2$: If $x \neq 0$, $\lambda = -1$ from the first equation, hence $y=-\frac{1}{2}$, $x^2=\frac12$, hence $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Can you find the minimum and maximum now?

Comment about your working:

From $$2x=\lambda(-2x)$$

We have $$2x(1+\lambda)=0$$

The right conclusion can be $x=0$ or $\lambda = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (graphical method): Consider the contour curve:
$$x^2+y^2=z,$$
which is a circle center $(0,0)$ and the radius $\sqrt{z}.$

Hence the largest circle intersecting the parabola is through the points $(-2,3), (2,3)$ and the smallest circle is through the vertex of the parabola $(0,-1)$ or the tangent to parabola and the circle (which is a little challenging).